# Is there way to know what headers can be accepted by HTTP server?

Tags: http, security, https, network-programming, httpserver

Imagine that there is server required authentication for getting an access to some endpoint.

And developer added some logic to bypass the authentication: if server recieve HTTP header `give_me_access=true`, then server answers without requiring authenticaton.

Is there way for an attacker to know that the server accept this header?

Comment: This is really a question for [security.se].

Comment: There are very few server that are so kindly to mention which header they are missing in an error message. May be using some timing attacks you may be able to identify if a header entry is processed by the server.

Comment: Unless the attacker had access to the server code, or otherwise had sniffed the HTTP traffic and saw the `give_me_access=true` header being used in practice, then no, they would not know that the `give_me_access=true` header was supported.